# Нужна загрузка из БД

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, three.js

Вот весь код https://jsfiddle.net/eqccoee6/
Есть сайт который загружает obj модели в строке 88 происходит указание модели

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load('obj/Monkey.obj', function (loadedMesh)
```

как сделать так чтобы все фигуры хранились в БД, и загружались оттуда.

Comment: За вас повесить сервер, создать базу данных и написать серверную сторону клиента?

Comment: @Den есть сервер,база.
я просто не пойму "как написать серверную сторону клиента?"
просто как обычное подключение к БД или там что то особенное нужно?

Comment: Всё засисит от того что вы хотите сделать, если это просто для дома проэкт то да - тупо запросы в БД. Слишком расплывчатый вопрос для того что-бы сказать что-то конкретное

Comment: @Den а если не для дома,то как лучше сделать?